# Variable display issue in Razor page in Blazor App

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm learning Blazor. On my page the contents of the _persons list just flashes by when I click the Search button, is this variable being garbage collected? Thanks in advance.

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorPorter.Models
@using BlazorPorter.Context
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@inject SqliteContext SqliteContext
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<form class="form-control">
    <input placeholder="id" @bind="_id"/>
    <input placeholder="name" @bind="_name"/>
    <button class="btn-primary" @onclick="@Insert">Insert</button>
</form>

<form class="form-control">
    <button class="btn-primary" @onclick="Search">Search</button>
</form>
@if (_persons != null)
{
    @foreach (Person p in _persons)
    {
        <p>@p.Id</p>
        <p>@p.Name</p>
    }
}

@code
{
    private string? _id;
    private string? _name;
    private List<Person>? _persons;

    private async Task Insert()
    {
        if (_id != null && _name != null)
        {
            await SqliteContext.AddAsync(new Person() { Id = _id, Name = _name });
            await SqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Search()
    {
        if (SqliteContext.Persons != null)
        {
            _persons = SqliteContext.Persons.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought the SqliteContext wasn't querying the content because it wasn't showing up on the page. But after I debugged it using breakpoints, I realized it was there. On successive clicks of the Search button, the content of the _persons list also flashes.

Comment: `<button type="button"...` or handle the forms `@onsubmit`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to
`@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender:false))` or 
`@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))`
to disable prerender.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering 
The page rendered twice (prerender , interactiveserver), so it flashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@code
{
    // ... other code ...

    private async Task Insert()
    {
        // ... existing code ...
    }

    private async Task Search()
    {
        _persons = await SqliteContext.Persons.ToListAsync();
        StateHasChanged(); // Explicitly tell Blazor to re-render the component
    }
}
```

Convert the Search method to asynchronous `(async Task)` and use `await` when fetching data from the database, followed by calling `StateHasChanged()` to ensure UI updates properly.